# Why is my 3D model missing a Geoface with a Skinned Mesh Renderer inside?

Tags: unity-game-engine, model, 3d, fbx

So I'm using someone else's 3D model "YunaRig(1)" and am trying to make it compatible with a tool called "Face Cap for Unity" which apparently requires a Geo Face on your model for it to work.

The FaceCap example FBX ("FaceCapHead") has something called "GeoFace" which contains a Skinned Mesh Renderer which, I suppose, points to the other (black and white) 'GeoFace' as seen in the pic.

*My* YunaRig(1) FBX has a black and white 'Face_GEO' in it, but not a colored "Face_GEO" with a SkinnedMeshRenderer to point to the the black and white mesh 'Face_GEO'... if that makes sense.

I was hoping someone could tell me how to get a "Face_GEO" with a SkinnedMeshRenderer pointing to the black and white 'Face_GEO' inside.

I don't know how to work with 3D models, so I'm super lost! Thanks for any advice and hopefully my question even makes sense.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black and white "geoFace" is the mesh, it contains all the geometrical data needed to display the model ([Vertex and their connections to each other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh))
"FaceCapHead" has  colors because the Skinned Mesh Renderer has [Materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Material.html) that describe what colors to show on which triangle.

If i understand correctly you need a Skinned Mesh Renderer on your YunaRig, You can just drag and drop YunaRig in the scene and add a new Component "[Skinned Mesh Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SkinnedMeshRenderer.html)" to the main object. After that you need to link the Attribute Mesh with "Body", Root Bone with "Hips" and under Materials add the desired Material (if you have colored Materials)